# Contador de Clicks usando Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu estou tentando fazer um contador de cliques.    
**Entenda**: tenho uma barra de pesquisa que retorna dinâmicamente todos os títulos de serviços cadastrados no banco de dados. Esse processo intermedia entre o `PHP` e o `Javascript`. Mas isso já foi feito.

Se eu digito "**Blog**" na pesquisa, o `javascript` envia a requisição e retorna os resultados encontrados com aquele termo. Eu defini que o resultado viesse com um link para a página do serviço e isso está acontecendo 100% sem problemas.

Ocorre que eu também quero contabilizar quando esse link for clicado, ou seja, eu quero gravar em uma tabela do banco de dados cada click ocorrido. Porém por mais que eu tente, não consigo achar um jeito de fazer isso, eu até entendo a lógica mas estou esquecendo de fazer algo ou não consegui formular bem a lógica do processo. Preciso que me ajudem.

Vou deixar aqui o script que estou utilizando. Como uma busca pode retornar dinamicamente mais de 1 resultado, esse *loop* foi feito dentro de uma function `javascript`. Entenda bem as partes:

**- Barra de pesquisa**

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <div class="inner-form">
        <div class="input-field second-wrap">
            <input id="busca" name="pesquisar" type="text" placeholder="Qual serviço você está procurando?" />
            <div style="background: #efefef;">
                <ul id='results' style='list-style: none;margin: 0;'>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field third-wrap">
            <button class="btn-search" id="btnSearch" type="button">
            Pesquisar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**- Detecta a digitação para disparo da função de busca**

```
document.getElementById("busca").onkeyup = function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
        var q = this.value === "" ? "*" : this.value;
        sendSearch(q);
    }
};
```

**- Envia termos para o PHP para realizar a busca**

```
function sendSearch(q) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/sistema/Teste.php?val="+q, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState===4&&xmlhttp.status===200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            var resultado = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
                resultado +=
                    "<li style='padding: 7px 0'><a data-click='' data-target='" + json[i].id +"' style='color: #48556b;' href='" + json[i].uri + "'><h5 class='m-0'>"+ json[i].nome +"</h5></a></li>";
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = resultado;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Baseado na estrutura html e nas informações que foram inseridas no loop de resultado da função javascript, foi criado o script para contabilizar o click**

```
$("[data-click]").click(function () {
    let idClick = $(this).attr("data-target") ? $(this).attr("data-target") : $(this).html();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/sistema/Counter.php',
        data: {'idClick': idClick},
        type: 'GET',
        success: false
    });
});
```

**- Por fim, o PHP**

```
//Counter.php
$id_click = $_GET['idClick'];

$count_click = $db->Executar("UPDATE servicos SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE id = '$id_click'");
```

Eu quero que ao clicar nesse link, ele vá para a página de serviço mas contabilize o click também. Seguindo o que escrevi pensei que daria certo mas ao que parece, a página `Counter.php` não está recebendo o parâmetro `idClick`.

Para quem puder me ajudar a esclarecer o que estou fazendo de errado ou como posso modificar para que ela funcione, serei grato.

Desde já agradeço a todos que lerem e ajudarem com alguma sugestão.

Obrigado.
NOTA: ***Se precisarem de informações adicionais, por favor, pergunte nos comentários.***

Comment: Acredito que seja porque, ao clicar no link, a página é redirecionada e não executa o AJAX antes.

Comment: @Sam Mano, realmente, pode ser isso, mas tipo. Estive pesquisando um código de um colega meu que ele fez um sistema básico de imobiliária para um cliente e ele usou esse conceito (na vdd ele fez um sistema bem complexo com classes, construct, etc). Ele clica no link envia para a outra página e o javascript envia o valor capturado via AJax. Até essa parte eu me baseei no dele. :/

Comment: O ideal mesmo era fazer isso no PHP. Via JS dá pra redirecionar após o AJAX ser processado, mas se o cara abrir o link numa nova guia, não vai pegar o click e não vai chamar o AJAX.

Comment: o que o @Sam disse faz todo sentido. Se não quiser usar `Ajax`, pode direcionar para uma pagina que irá fazer o que precisa, e depois dessa pagina direcionar para outra

Comment: @RicardoPontual Eu sempre faço isso quando quero contar cliques. Crio uma página PHP que recebe o ID e a URL de destino, faz o update no banco e redireciona. :)

Comment: Exato @Sam, funciona muito bem, quase um protetor de links :)

Comment: E poderiam me ajudar com um exemplo dessa utilização?